# Assigning values to associative array with dynamic keys

Tags: php

I have `$options` as an associative array with each value as mixed(can be strings, or other arrays). I won't have any objects there.
`$keys` is a numeric array & the number of keys is determined at runtime.

I want to have a result similar to this expression
`$options[$keys[0]][$keys[1]].......[$keys[count($keys)-1]] = $value;`

For example, if `$keys = array('key1')`, i want to do
`$options['key1'] = $value;`
& if `$keys = array('key1', 'key2')`, i want to do
`$options['key1']['key2'] = $value;`
& so on

The problem with array_replace_recursive is that $value may itself be an array. Someway to constrain the depth to which array_replace_recursive can go? or maybe some other way?

Comment: Seems like a very complicated structure for storing options - maybe you should reconsider your design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working. Thanks to @Benjamin Paap. His answer helped to get to the exact solution

```
$options = array('key1' => array('key2' => array('key3' => 'value')));
$keys = array('key1', 'key2', 'key3');

$length = count($keys);
$search = &$options;
foreach ($keys as $key => $value) {
    // key doesn't exist or value is not an array
    if(!isset($search[$value]) || !is_array($search)) {
        $search = (array) $search;
        $search[$value] = array();
    }

    $search = &$search[$value];

    // last iteration
    if($length - 1 === $key) {
        $search = 'new value';
    }
}
unset($search);
var_dump($options);
```

Answer (score 1):

I made something similar like this:

```
$options = array('key1' => array('key2' => array('key3' => 'value')));
$keys = array('key1', 'key2', 'key3');

$search = &$options;
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $search = &$search[$key];
}
$search = 'changed value';

var_dump($options);
```

You could always create references to the next key.

Comment: but then `$search` will have the string 'value'. What i want is to update the original string to some new value so that finally i get `array('key1' => array('key2' => array('key3' => 'changed value')))`

Comment: Yeah i had it working, see my answer. I +1'd your answer as it was the one that set me on the right path. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible, As array is a data structure and you can not put code or loop inside it. Let me google i will update you once i get some solution :)